# I have an old domain that I'm retiring. How do I set up a permanent redirect from the old domain to the new one?

Tags: dns, redirects

I originally posted this as one of the defining questions for the site so I thought I'd ask it again.

Currently I have DNS for both domains pointing to the same place but I'd like to set up a permanent redirect from the old one to the new one for any lingering links out in the wild.

Answer (score 4):

This page lists how to do it using common web languages. Note the section entitled "Redirect Old domain to New domain"
http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php

Also, Google has provided a nice article on what to consider when moving your site.
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=83105&hl=en

Comment: Also of note, Google allows you to submit a redirect notice directly to them through Google's webmaster tools.  This give them more than just a 301 redirect.  It tells them I was over here and now I am over there.